# How to dynamically update the location of the marker on mapbox in android?

Tags: android, location, mapbox

I use MapBox develop a map application, my server will return some latitude and longitude data,I need to update marker location through latitude and longitude

so my code like this:

```
override fun updateDroneLocationResult(drone:Drone) {
    var latLng = LatLng(drone.latitude, drone.longitude)
    droneMaker = map.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(latLng))
    map.updateMarker(droneMaker!!)
}
```

but the function "updateMarker" is not working, I don't know where's wrong.
what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating existing marker instead adding new marker each time. If you want to update existing one do something like this:

```
  if(mCurrLocationMarker!=null){
        mCurrLocationMarker.setPosition(latLng);
    }else{
        mCurrLocationMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(latLng);
    }
```

also if you want to navigate or move the camera to this marker also call:

```
   map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: it still not working, The marker is still not moving with the latitude and longitude

Comment: check the value of longitude and latitude if it's correct or not and also post code what you are trying now.

Comment: I am very sure that the parameters have been passed in. my code like this: https://gist.github.com/ShawnSWu/47d84752cfca424a7351f892d3d2a11e

Answer (score 0):

I fix my problem, it is the problem with the simulator, I have no problem with the physical phone.